# Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

When finishing the React Native application, I came across this error.
As I understand it is a problem with FlatList.
I started useState of incidents as an empty array.

Does anyone know how it could solve?

[GitHub project - Be The Hero](https://github.com/zehguilherme/semana-omnistack-11)

[Ivalid Violation error - React Native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiH61.jpg)

[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/zehguilherme/415648e6fec3b8a7af53b47d14d04b65)

Comment: The error is because your FlatList is rendering before the data arrives, because of it incidents initially will be a promise, that's the reason you are getting the above error.

Comment: check whats the data you are  getting after this line setIncidents(response.data) by consoling incidents.

Comment: I noticed that brackets were missing inside setIncidents, since the objects are 2 vectors.

Comment: Does it fixed your issue?

Comment: Yes, in the end it was just a typo. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and Goskula Jayachandra's comment keyed me in and solved the problem.

> The error is because your FlatList is rendering before the data arrives, because of it incidents initially will be a promise, that's the reason you are getting the above error.

**How do I prevent FlastList from rendering before data?**

Follow along in the code snippet below, I've added descriptive comments.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

const Toolbox = () => {
  // Define state for loading, defining default value of true
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      
  useEffect(() => {
    // Get your data to populate the FlatList, then set your loading state to false
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    // Basic ternary operator: if isLoading (true), then display ActivityIndicator, else display FlatList
    {isLoading ? (
      <ActivityIndicator /> // Don't forget to include ActivityIndicator
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          //...
        />
      )
    }
  );
};

export default Toolbox;
```